# Laravel Get Model Count with Zero Relationship Count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

At the moment, I've got a variable being shared to all of my views through the App Service Provide through the following lines:

```
    $emptyManifestsCount = Carrier_Manifest::withCount('shipments')
        ->where('carrierOrigin','>',1)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $now])
        ->count();
    View::share('emptyManifestsCount', $emptyManifestsCount);
```

My problem is that I wanted to narrow it down even more to those `Carrier_Manifest` with a `shipment` count of 0 (as in there are no current relationships between it and the `shipments`.

At the current moment, this returns me the correct count of `Carrier_Manifests` between the date and time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `has` function.

```
$emptyManifestsCount = Carrier_Manifest::has('shipments', 0)
    ->where('carrier_origin', '>', 1)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $now])
    ->count();
```